# Вывести элементы массива в единственном числе не используя встроенные функции php

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно вывести элементы 2, 5, 3, 10

Что доделать в моём коде, что бы он вывел эти элементы?

```
<?php
   $arr = array(2, 5, 5, 3 ,2, 10);

   for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++ ) {
      for ($j=0; $j < $i; $j++ ) {
         if($arr[$i]==$arr[$j]) echo $arr[$i]. " ";
      }
   }
?>
```

Сейчас выводит только 2, 5. Нужно чтобы ещё 3, 10 выводил.

Comment: а что сейчас не так? что сейчас выводит? что вы делаете в этом коде? для чего вы это делаете по вашему замыслу? хоть какие-нибудь пояснения можно?........мне просто интересно: вы самим понимаете, что вы написали?

Comment: Ну я написал такую логику, что скрипт будет выводить только повторяющие элементы в массиве в одном числе. А мне надо чтобы остальные тоже выводились

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так должно работать

```
<?php

$arr = array(2, 5, 5, 3 ,2, 10);
$arr_copy = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++ ) {
   $ret = 1;
   for($j = 0; $j < count($arr_copy); $j++){
      if($arr[$i] == $arr_copy[$j]){
         $ret = 0;
      }
   }
   if($ret == 1){
      $arr_copy[count($arr_copy)] = $arr[$i];
      echo $arr[$i]. " ";
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51309/discussion-on-answer-by-yuri--------).

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ в лоб

```
$inputArray = array(2, 5, 5, 3 ,2, 10);
$outputArray = array();


// вся работа происходит тут
foreach($inputArray as $inputArrayItem) {
    foreach($outputArray as $outputArrayItem) {
        if($inputArrayItem == $outputArrayItem) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    $outputArray[] = $inputArrayItem;
}


// это уже вывод итогового результата
foreach($outputArray as $output) {
    echo $output.'<br>';
}
```

из [доков](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.continue.php):

> **continue** принимает необязательный числовой аргумент, который указывает на скольких уровнях вложенных циклов будет пропущена оставшаяся часть итерации. Значением по умолчанию является 1, при которой пропускается оставшаяся часть текущего цикла.

---

Есть еще один рабочий способ, который я подглядел в каком-то месте, но который я сам пока не понимаю как работает))

```
$array = array(2, 5, 5, 3 ,2, 10);
$unique = array();

foreach($array as $v)
  isset($k[$v]) || ($k[$v] = 1) && $unique[] = $v; 

// результат 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($unique);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Хех, недурно :)

Comment: continue 2; - это как понять?

Comment: @Sven http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.continue.php `continue принимает необязательный числовой аргумент, который указывает на скольких уровнях вложенных циклов будет пропущена оставшаяся часть итерации. Значением по умолчанию является 1, при которой пропускается оставшаяся часть текущего цикла.` и там же есть пример аж с `continue 3`

Comment: ок, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите как я ещё переделал

```
$arr = array(2, 5, 5, 3 ,2, 10, 10, 0);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++ ) {
   $ret = 1;
   for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
      if($arr[$i] == $arr[$j]){
         $ret = 0;
      }
   }
   if($ret == 1){
      echo $arr[$i]. " ";
   }
}
```

Тоже ж можно так вроде

Comment: Yuri, Алексей, посоветуйте плиз, имеет право такое тоже на жизнь? Просто так минимальный код вышел у меня и вроде работает логика

Comment: Да, такое решение имеет ) Я проверил - код рабочий